# incompatible pointer type

Tags: c, arrays, function, pointers, types

I just started programming so pointers and arrays confuse me.
This program just assigns random numbers from 0 - 9 into array and prints them out

```
(#include <stdio.h> #include <stdlib.h> #include <time.h>)

int function(int *num[]){                         
     int i;
     for(i=0; i<10; i++){
          srand((unsigned)time(NULL));
          *num[i] = rand()%10;                     
          printf("%d", *num[i]);
     }
     return 0;
}

int main(){
     int num[10];
     function(&num);              // incompatable pointer type (how do i fix this?)
     return 0;
}
```

Thankyou

Comment: You might want to move the srand((unsigned)time(NULL)); outside the for() loop.

Answer (score 6):

Change your code to read something like this:

```
int function(int num[]){                          
     int i; 
     for(i=0; i<10; i++){ 
          srand((unsigned)time(NULL)); 
          num[i] = rand()%10;                      
          printf("%d", num[i]); 
     } 
     return 0; 
} 

int main(){ 
     int num[10]; 
     function(num);
     return 0; 
}
```

In `main()`, you are allocating an array of 10 integers. The call to `function(num)` passes the *address* of this array (technically, the address of the first element of the array) to the `function()` function. In a parameter declaration, `int num[]` is almost exactly equivalent to `int *num` (I'll let you ponder on that one). Finally, when you access the elements of `num[]` from within the function, you don't need any extra `*`. By using `num[i]`, you are accessing the `i`'th element of the array pointed to by `num`.

It may help to remember that in C, the following are exactly the same:

```
num[i]
*(num+i)
```

Comment: No one has said this yet, but he should _actually_ change it to `int function(int num[], size_t len)`. Safety, people!

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to pass in a pointer to your array. Just pass in the array. I have fixed your pointer code below.

Also, you should not reset the seed (srand) through every iteration through the for loop.

```
int function(int num[]){                          
     int i; 
     srand((unsigned(time(NULL));
     for(i=0; i<10; i++){ 
          num[i] = rand()%10;                      
          printf("%d", num[i]); 
     } 
     return 0; 
}

int main(){ 
     int num[10]; 
     function(num);  
     return 0; 
}
```

Comment: -1 - This doesn't answer the actual programming issue he has with pointers.

Answer (score 1):

It all depends on what you want to achieve in the end.

**(1)** If your function `function` is intended to be used with arrays of run-time size, then you have to pass a pointer to the first element of the array. That is achieved by the following equivalent declarations

```
int function(int *num)
```

or

```
int function(int num[])
```

Inside the function you have to access the passed array as

```
num[i] = rand() % 10;
```

And you call your function as

```
function(num);
```

Of course, when the array size is a run-time value, it makes sense to pass that size to the function as well, meaning that your function should have the following interface

```
int function(int num[], size_t n)
```

And implement it for an array of size `n`, instead of hardcoding `10` directly into your implementation.

**(2)** If your function `function` is intended to be used with arrays of fixed compile-time size (`10` in this case), then the better approach would be to pass a pointer to the entire array. It is achieved by the following declaration

```
int function(int (*num)[10])
```

Inside the function you have to access the passed array as

```
(*num)[i] = rand() % 10;
```

And you call your function as

```
function(&num);
```

So it is either (1) or (2).

What you currently have in your code looks like a mix of these two approaches. More precisely, you code looks like an attempt to implement the *second* approach, but it is missing some important parentheses :)

Most answers given to you so far suggest using the first approach. However, seeing that the array size is actually a compile-time constant in your case, I would suggest sticking with the second approach.

Answer (score 0):

Use either `int *num` or `int num[]`, don't use both together as you have right now (`int *num[]`). An array is passed to a function as a pointer to the first element, i.e. `int *num`, which is equivalent to `int num[]`.